# Как выводить названия ячеек в строке из CSV через GREP?

Tags: linux, grep

Есть csv файл, я делаю обычный поиск в нём по каким-либо данным через GREP и мне выдаёт строку с текстом:

> John Doe; info@mail.com

Но в самом вверху csv есть названия name; email и т.д.
Можно ли их как-то выводить в строке?

> name: John Doe; email: info@mail.com

Comment: Однострочником вряд ли, проще скрипт написать. Вычитать заголовок а потом вычитывать строки и выводить как нравится

Comment: Тебе наверное https://github.com/johnkerl/miller подойдёт.